# How to split the month value into days value by R or python?

Tags: python, r, date

## My data:

```
Month  column_1 column_2
201801  31      62
201802  28      56
...
201812
```

## I want the output can be:

```
Date       column_1  column_2
2018-01-01    1        2
2018-01-02    1        2
...
2018-01-31    1        2
2018-02-01    1        2
...
2018-12-31   ..........
```

I want to average each month value into date value.

Which function can i reference to do that ?
Thank you so much.

Comment: In both your desired output and your data, what are value_1 and value_2?

Comment: are column name,  I edited, sorry for any confused.

Comment: I know that, but what does the value inside the column mean?

Comment: the output date value is the average on month value, for example: 201801 value = 31, output: 2018-01-01 = 31(value of 201801)/31(no.of day on 201801) = 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow these steps to expand your dataframe's rows from monthly to daily values, and then display the average daily value for each monthly value in your columns.

Let's start with a dataframe similar to the example you gave, but just for January and February:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'column_1':[31,28], 'column_2':[62,56]}, index=[201801, 201802])
df.index.name='Month'
```

Which looks like:

```
        column_1    column_2
Month       
201801        31          62
201802        28          56
```

Now we need to reformat how the months in the index are displayed, so that we can change the index's datatype to a Pandas [period_range](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.period_range.html):

```
df.index = df.index.map(str)
df.index = df.index.str[0:4] + '-' + df.index.str[-2:]
df.index = pd.period_range(start=df.index.values[0], periods=len(df.index.values), freq='m')
```

Running the following line enables us to convert the monthly rows into rows for each day:

```
df = df.resample('D').ffill()
```

Now, we have entries for each day that looks like this:

```
            column_1  column_2
2018-01-01        31        62
2018-01-02        31        62
2018-01-03        31        62
2018-01-04        31        62
...
2018-02-25        28        56
2018-02-26        28        56
2018-02-27        28        56
2018-02-28        28        56
```

But we're not quite done yet. We still need to display the *daily* averages of these monthly values. In order to do this, we need to know the number of days in each calendar month. The following steps allow us to get the number of days for each month, and then calculate the daily averages for each row of a column, without using a for-loop:

```
daily = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M')).count()
daily = daily.iloc[:,0]
daily = daily.resample('D').ffill().rename('days_in_month')
df = df.join(daily)
cols = ['column_1', 'column_2']
for col in cols:
    df[col] = df[col]/df['days_in_month']
df = df.drop('days_in_month', axis=1)
```

Now our dataframe is in the proper format, and is displaying the average daily value (averaged over the number of calendar days in that month) of each month's value:

```
            column_1    column_2
2018-01-01       1.0         2.0
2018-01-02       1.0         2.0
2018-01-03       1.0         2.0
2018-01-04       1.0         2.0
2018-01-05       1.0         2.0
...
2018-02-24       1.0         2.0
2018-02-25       1.0         2.0
2018-02-26       1.0         2.0
2018-02-27       1.0         2.0
2018-02-28       1.0         2.0
```